# Where's the rest of the IronPython exception?

Tags: python, exception, ironpython

I could be wrong, but it seems I'm only getting incomplete stack traces and exception messages when a `SystemError` is raised in IronPython. I'm doing this:

```py
try:
    with SQLConnection(DATASOURCES[SCHEDULEDB]) as db:
        db.execute_sql( command + ' ' + ','.join(block) + ';' )
except Exception, e:
    print 'caught an exception'
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    print e
    raise
finally:
    db.close()
    engine.close()
```

However, all I'm seeing is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
SystemError: The connection has been disabled.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```py
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
```

Instead of printing the exception object directly.  In Python, exception objects don't hold onto the stack trace directly—instead they're part of the trio of items in `sys.exc_info()`.

You could also do:

```py
import System
...

except System.Exception, e:
```

and you'll get a normal .NET exception object instead of the Python exception object.

Answer (score 1):

There are some flags on the IronPython process that will set .NET exceptions to dump their stack trace as well:

```
ipy -X:ShowClrExceptions -X:ExceptionDetail my_script.py args
```